# Visual studio code will not activate conda env specified in launch.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My launch.json config looks as follows:

{

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "python": "/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/env_name/bin/python",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
    }
]
```

}

However, when I run the debugger, the specified env_name is not run. Instead the default interpreter python version (3.10) is run. Why is the specified environment not being activated?